# Text does not resize on screen resize

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, carousel

I'm using the text-only carousel seen here:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/gXN2u/)
Here is my resize code:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", resetCarousel);
function resetCarousel(){
    setCarouselHeight('#carousel-text');
    $('#carousel-text').carousel({
        interval: 15000
    });
```

The problem is that when the screen resizes the div enclosing all the text items does not resize accordingly (i.e. it's not responsive). The setCarouselHeight function is used to determine the largest height required for all text items to display. I need the setCarouselHeight to be fired every time the screen resizes. When I do it manually (i,e, window.onresize=func), even after using a timeout, the item sizes reflect the ones used in the old position, not the resized position. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of toying with this and coming oh so close, I tried the Owl carousel and got what I needed right away. In the end it is much simpler than bootstrap's. The key is to use the AutoHeight example and turn autoheight to false. It automatically sizes the div to the tallest text piece you have and is very responsive. http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to use `js` or `owl` plugin for responsive the slider. It's can be done by simple css query. My css is below:

```
.carousel-inner>.item{
  min-height:350px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .carousel-inner>.item{
    min-height:250px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:569px){
  .carousel-inner>.item{
    min-height:200px;
  }
}
```

Check my live demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/gXN2u/556/)

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure I was clear enough in describing the issue. The original code goes through all the text items and presizes the container for the largest one. That way the screen isn't jumping all around with different sizes for different text. I wanted to do this in a carousel. The example I gave that you changed works upon loading, but when you resize the screen it fails. The Owl carousel works flawlessly.